# retrieving subset of entities with many to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc application using hibernate, jpa, and MySQL, I have a ManyToMany relationship between two entities: `Provider` and `FacilityAddress`.  I am trying to populate a list of all `Providers` who are located at a specific `FacilityAddress`, however, I am currently getting the following error message when the code for doing so is called:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:  
Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'
```

I do not know if this error is caused at the entity level, the jpa level. Can someone show me how to fix my code so this error goes away?

Note, all of the required code is in this posting, but some of it is at a file sharing site to which I am giving links.  For example:
The [Provider entity code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/nYigI3CTvEmXJo89ftWF?b=L5nbv3AsgEtYrdtNmnJv).
The [FacilityAddress code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/V4xBVwm86ly5A5Lg4yGF?b=UXj2ryTjLo0wAZ0rAlYQ).
The [Person entity code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/4sdK4xTom7mW1kC5JV0g?b=tBqbKukTRbNlUYM0Dio5).
The  [BaseEntity code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/rYHzIV7P3fQKZ4qEalZD?b=ndIjMOqNwwx0mryvcvHM).
The [ProviderTitle code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/txgQeJl8HbqUudPm2FtI?b=mZ3b7V0yTUihfp82Qrcf).
The [NamedEntity code is at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/3tdpbNyCeHgxH9GEQGnd?b=uqmnTJIB30T93VMk9lDW).

Here is the relevant part of the controller code which starts the sequence of events that eventually triggers the error when called:

```
@RequestMapping("/calendar")
public String showCalendar(@RequestParam("day") String day, org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
    //omitting some irrelevant code
    //get list of providers
    List<Provider> ps = (List<Provider>) clinicService.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(7);
    for(int g=0;g<ps.size();g++){
        System.out.println(" ----------- provider name is: "+ps.get(g).getFirstName());
    }

    return "appointments/calendar";
}
```

Here is the method in clinicService which is called by the code above:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Collection<Provider> findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(int id) throws DataAccessException {
    return providerRepository.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(id);
}
```

Here is the method in the providerRepository (JpaProviderRepository.java) which is called from the preceding step:

```
@Override
public Collection<Provider> findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(int id) {
    // using 'join fetch' because a single query should load both owners and pets
    // using 'left join fetch' because it might happen that an owner does not have pets yet
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< inside Jpa Repository findByFacilityId() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT provider FROM Provider provider left join fetch provider.facilities pf WHERE pf.id =:id");
    System.out.println("========================= Just set query. ");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    System.out.println("------------------------- Just added parameter to query. ");
    List<Provider> p = (List<Provider>) query.getResultList();
    System.out.println("------------------------- Just created ProviderCompany object from query result. ");
    return p;
}
```

Here is the sql that creates the relevant objects in the MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provider_titles(
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80),
  INDEX(name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providers(
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(80),
  last_name VARCHAR(80),
  title_id INT(4) UNSIGNED,
  comments VARCHAR(300),
  FOREIGN KEY (title_id) REFERENCES provider_titles(id),
  INDEX(last_name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS facilityAddresses(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  company_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  type_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  facilityname varchar(50),
  address varchar(200),
  city varchar(200),
  state_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  zip varchar(50),
  isHQ bool,
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES providerCompanies(id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES locationTypes(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES states(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providerOfficeJunction(
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  provider_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  providerOffice_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (provider_id) REFERENCES providers(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (providerOffice_id) REFERENCES facilityAddresses(id)
);
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< inside Jpa Repository findByFacilityId() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
========================= Just set query. 
------------------------- Just added parameter to query. 
Hibernate: select distinct provider0_.id as id1_29_0_, facilityad2_.id as id1_12_1_, provider0_.first_name as first2_29_0_, provider0_.last_name as last3_29_0_, provider0_.title_id as title4_29_0_, facilityad2_.address as address2_12_1_, facilityad2_.city as city3_12_1_, facilityad2_.company_id as company7_12_1_, facilityad2_.facilityname as facility4_12_1_, facilityad2_.isHQ as isHQ5_12_1_, facilityad2_.type_id as type8_12_1_, facilityad2_.state_id as state9_12_1_, facilityad2_.zip as zip6_12_1_, facilities1_.provider_id as provider1_29_0__, facilities1_.providerOffice_id as provider2_24_0__ from providers provider0_ left outer join providerOfficeJunction facilities1_ on provider0_.id=facilities1_.provider_id left outer join facilityAddresses facilityad2_ on facilities1_.providerOffice_id=facilityad2_.id where facilityad2_.id=?
Hibernate: select providerti0_.id as id1_28_3_, providerti0_.name as name2_28_3_, providerti0_.provider_id as provider3_28_3_, provider1_.id as id1_29_0_, provider1_.first_name as first2_29_0_, provider1_.last_name as last3_29_0_, provider1_.title_id as title4_29_0_, emails2_.provider_id as provider3_29_5_, emails2_.id as id1_27_5_, emails2_.id as id1_27_1_, emails2_.name as name2_27_1_, emails2_.provider_id as provider3_27_1_, providerti3_.id as id1_28_2_, providerti3_.name as name2_28_2_, providerti3_.provider_id as provider3_28_2_ from provider_titles providerti0_ left outer join providers provider1_ on providerti0_.provider_id=provider1_.id left outer join provider_email emails2_ on provider1_.id=emails2_.provider_id left outer join provider_titles providerti3_ on provider1_.title_id=providerti3_.id where providerti0_.id=?
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'
INFO  DefaultLoadEventListener - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
WARN  LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@76f10c77<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@59441dc0>
WARN  CollectionLoadContext - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [5] entries
WARN  warn - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.util.CallMonitoringAspect.invoke(CallMonitoringAspect.java:80) ~[CallMonitoringAspect.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy43.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.service.ClinicServiceImpl.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(ClinicServiceImpl.java:185) ~[ClinicServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy46.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.web.EncounterController.showCalendar(EncounterController.java:173) ~[EncounterController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73) [datatables-core-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71) [datatables-servlet2-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2117) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:648) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1107) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:963) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.repository.jpa.JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.findProvidersByFacilityAddressId(JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.java:103) ~[JpaProviderRepositoryImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-tx-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar:4.2.1.Final]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think I can help you but please add you Entities Provider and the facilities attribute. Also FacilityAddress entity class

Comment: @Koitoer The code for the entities `Provider` and `FacilityAddress` is at the hyperlinks in the original posting above.  Just click on the links.  As a reference, the `FacilityAddress` code is at https://jumpshare.com/v/V4xBVwm86ly5A5Lg4yGF?b=UXj2ryTjLo0wAZ0rAlYQ  and the `Provider` code is at https://jumpshare.com/v/nYigI3CTvEmXJo89ftWF?b=L5nbv3AsgEtYrdtNmnJv  The other entities from which these two inherit are also included in the hyperlinks in my original posting above.  Does this help you see the problem?

Comment: The problem is in you provider_titles table (ProviderTitle class presumably).

Comment: @Ean Thank you. I just edited my original posting above to include links to the code for `ProviderTitle` and another entity that it inherits, in addition to adding the sql that creates the `provider_titles` table in the underlying database. Does this help you identify the problem?

Comment: I added an answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts.

When I see

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provider_titles(
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80),
  INDEX(name)
);
```

Basically there are two fields in the table id and name.
When I review the entity that map that class I found

```
public class ProviderTitle extends NamedEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
    private Provider provider;
```

And

@MappedSuperclass

```
public class NamedEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

And

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;
```

Using that hierachy

Entity ProviderTitle have 3 properties [id,name,provider] with the column names [id, name, **provider_id**] and table only have 2 properties defined so query will fail

Reviewing the code of the failing query it seems this.

Hibernate: select providerti0_.id as id1_28_3_, providerti0_.name as name2_28_3_, **providerti0_.provider_id** as provider3_28_3_, provider1_.id as id1_29_0_, provider1_.first_name as first2_29_0_, provider1_.last_name as last3_29_0_, provider1_.title_id as title4_29_0_, emails2_.provider_id as provider3_29_5_, emails2_.id as id1_27_5_, emails2_.id as id1_27_1_, emails2_.name as name2_27_1_, emails2_.provider_id as provider3_27_1_, providerti3_.id as id1_28_2_, providerti3_.name as name2_28_2_, providerti3_.provider_id as provider3_28_2_ from provider_titles providerti0_ left outer join providers provider1_ on **providerti0_.provider_id**=provider1_.id left outer join provider_email emails2_ on provider1_.id=emails2_.provider_id left outer join provider_titles providerti3_ on provider1_.title_id=providerti3_.id where providerti0_.id=?

As you can see table does not have a column name provider_id, it is why query is failing to retrieve the result, consider check ProviderTitle to remove provider property or recreate your schema. That is the root cause.

**UPDATE**

Provider has ManyToOne to ProviderTitle

```
public class Provider extends Person {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="title_id")
    protected ProviderTitle title;
```

And

```
public class ProviderTitle extends NamedEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
    private Provider provider;
```

ProviderTitle have ManyToOne to provider.

So there are two unidireccional relationship, and each one needs its own column, consider use mappedBy, as provider_id is not a column in the table provider_titles as follow:

```
   public class ProviderTitle extends NamedEntity {

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="title")
        private Collection<Provider> provider;
```

Comment: What I'm saying is your Entity (ProviderTitle) that maps to the provider_titles, have 3 properties and the physical table only have 2, it means one property(column) is missing in your table according to your model. So when you tried to execute the query, hibernate create a query that use **from provider_titles providerti0** and is failing because try to obtain 3  fields (providerti0_.id which exists), (providerti0_.name which exists) but (providerti0_.provider_id does not exists) as you can see 3 belongs to providerti0_ which is the alias of provider_titles in the sql, is root cause of failing

Comment: Is the cause that why you are getting  \Unknown column 'providerti0_.provider_id' in 'field list'

Comment: I have another hibernate question.  Are you willing to help me solve it?  Here is the link to the new posting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002272/entity-relationship-not-populating-properly